# What are the tools I need to run robot test every time a deployment is triggered

Tags: automated-testing, robotframework

I'm trying to automatically trigger a robot test project which will not be run in local machine everytime there is a deployment. I need to know the tools I need to somehow execute the automation remotely or in cloud. Currently our team using jenkins, octopus deploy, github. are these tools enough for me to do what I just mentioned above. If not what are the tools I need to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You have tools already ,

You can run test in jenkins or octopus according to which tool you use for deployment .

Both Jenkins and octopus are just softwares that you can configure "What code to run on what System on what condition"

So you can configure "Trigger" that says "Run test code" on "New Deployment"

**For your case:**

1. Just add a test step in your Jenkins or octopus ( Depending on which
   of the tool uyou use for deployment. You have to trigger test after
   deployment so add test step after the deployment test on that
   project)
2. THe step is to "Run script" add the script to run your code
3. Configure target  ( Set to execute test in test server )

Comment: Yup, I tried searching online but what I found online is the robot script project that is triggered is on the local machine. I want to it to be something not dependent on local machine.

Comment: @Oelyu09 add the code to git repository , and in the step pull the test code to test server and trigger it

Comment: is the test server available in jenkins?

Comment: @Oelyu09 you can use Jenkins master it self as the server or you can add other agents

Comment: Thank you @PDHide